# Different line height for continuing row of list

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have a list and I want line items with long text to flow to the second row which would have a shorter line height than the line height between regular line items. For example:

```
<ul style="list-style:none">
<li>
Hotel Chain
</li>
<li>
Taxi Service
</li>
<li>
Tourist Trap & Retail Plaza
</li>
<li>
Travel Company
</li>
<li>
Local Olive Oil Company
</li>
</ul>
```

So hopefully that makes it clear what I'm wanting. Thanks for helping!

{EDIT}

I changed the code above.

The design is responsive, so when the screen shrinks the list width shrinks and some lines that took up one line then takes up two lines. I want those with two lines to have a shorter line height.

Comment: pls provide code and what you tried so far. otherwise its hard to help and understand what you exactly want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what effect you are trying to achieve but there is a pseudo-element of `::first-line` which might be what you are after

```css
ul {
  width: 200px;
 }

li {
  margin-bottom:1rem;
  line-height: 1;
}

li::first-line {
  line-height: 2;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>lorem</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam soluta ex ipsam dignissimos, provident assumenda!</li>
  <li>lorem</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam, magni!</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</li>
</ul>
```

[**::first-line @ MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-line)

Comment: That looks like the solution! Is there a way to add that style inline or give it a class so it will only affect the specific <ul> I want it to? I've tried giving the containing div and the ul classes but they don't work. Or rather, they work on all <ul> not just the ones with the specific class.

Comment: You can't do it inline but it should work with a specific class if you use the correct css selector such as `ul.myclass li::first-line`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that natively this paragraphs.

```
<p>First line item</p>
<p>Second line item</p>
<p>This is the third line item that will<br>wrap on a new line but have a<br>smallerline-height than others</p>
<p>Fourth line item</p>
<p>This fifth line item is the same as<br>the third in that its line-height<br>is different because it has multiple lines</p>
<p>And the sixth line is the same with<br>a smaller line-height</p>
```

No need to css, or you can specify a width to your paragraphs if you don't want do write the BRs.

http://jsfiddle.net/8q6wgw2x/